# JDBC - PostgreSQL - batch insert + unique index

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, jdbc

I have a table with unique constraint on some field. I need to insert a large number of records in this table. To make it faster I'm using batch update with JDBC (driver version is 8.3-603).
Is there a way to do the following:

- every batch execute I need to write into the table all the records from the batch that don't violate the unique index;
- every batch execute I need to receive the records from the batch that were not inserted into DB, so I could save "wrong" records

?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You need to write the rows into an intermediate table (without constraitns) first and then use SQL to copy the valid ones into the target table. Btw: why are you using such an outdated driver version?

Comment: I'd like to use newer version, but it isn't my decision :(
How can I use intermediate table more efficient? Copy line-by-line and delete copied, and then at the finish read records left in that table?

Comment: Look up "bulk upsert"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way of doing this would be something like this:

- create a staging table with the same structure as the target table but without the unique constraint
- batch insert all rows into that staging table. The most efficient way is to use `copy` or use the [CopyManager](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html) (although I don't know if that is already supported in your ancient driver version.

Once that is done you copy the valid rows into the target table:

```
insert into target_table(id, col_1, col_2)
select id, col_1, col_2
from staging_table 
where not exists (select *
                  from target_table 
                  where target_table.id = staging_table.id);
```

Note that the above is ***not*** concurrency safe! If other processes do the same thing you might still get unique key violations. To prevent that you need to lock the target table.

If you want to remove the copied rows, you could do that using a writeable CTE:

```
with inserted as (
    insert into target_table(id, col_1, col_2)
    select id, col_1, col_2
    from staging_table 
    where not exists (select *
                      from target_table 
                      where target_table.id = staging_table.id)
    returning staging_table.id;
) 
delete from staging_table
where id in (select id from inserted);
```

A (non-unique) index on the `staging_table.id` should help for the performance.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. How fast this way would be? Much slower then just batch insert straight to the target table?